# What is the "->" symbol called?

Tags: functional-programming, operators, java8

I have seen the `->` operator/symbol in Java 8 predicates recently and wondered what its name is. I know that it is used in lambda expressions, but I know that the symbol for lambda is λ, so that's not it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you type `λ` in ascii?

Comment: @Oded It's character number 229 (hex E5) in extended ascii: http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp869.html

Comment: Say the computer doesn't use the Greek Language code page, but the Hebrew one? 229 would be a Sigma (and no Lambda to be seen). Also - extended ascii (8 bit) is not ascii (7 bit).

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the info. But I'm not asking how to type the symbol. I'm asking what the "->" operator is called.

Comment: Well, the point was that it isn't easy to type `λ` on non-Greek keyboards... so that character can't be used ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called `arrow token`

Here on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Java), this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/lambda-expression-java-se-8)  and that [article](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html) or even on [java website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

> Many years ago, before there were any computers, the logician Alonzo Church wanted to formalize what it means for a mathematical function to be effectively computable. (Curiously, there are functions that are known to exist, but nobody knows how to compute their values.) He used the Greek letter lambda (λ) to mark parameters.
>
> Why the letter λ? Did Church run out of other letters of the alphabet? Actually, the venerable Principia Mathematica used the ˆ accent to denote free variables, which inspired Church to use an uppercase lambda (Λ) for parameters. But in the end, he switched to the lowercase version. Ever since, an expression with parameter variables has been called a "lambda expression."

Reference [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/lambda-expressions-in-java-8/240166764?pgno=1)

Comment: Rubyists call it the "stabby lambda", which I personally like more than "arrow token".

Comment: "stabby lambda" does sound catchy indeed!